# subtract values in different columns and different rows

Tags: sql

i have one table with the following values:

```
job name       start_dt         end_dt
gggggg         4/5/2013        5/5/2013
iiiii            6/5/13          7/8/13
```

I want to subract the `start_dt` of `gggggg` from `end_dt` of `iiiii`.

I am using this query:

```
select a.job_nm,(b.end_dt-a.start_dt) as difference from JOB a,b
where a.job_nm='ggggg' and b.job_nm='iiiii'.
```

This is giving me no output.

Comment: Which database engine are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

If this is SQL Server you can use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
select a.job_nm,
datediff(day, a.start_dt, b.end_dt) as [difference]
from JOB a,b
where a.job_nm='ggggg'
and b.job_nm='iiiii'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is conditional aggregation:

```
select (max(case when j.job_nm = 'iiiii' then b.end_dt end) - 
        max(case when j.job_nm = 'ggggg' then a.start_dt end)
       ) as difference
from Job j
where j.job_nm in ('ggggg', 'iiiii');
```

You can use the `datediff()` function, but for `datetimes` I find subtraction easier.